# FB login for hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, facebook-javascript-sdk, ibm-mobilefirst, facebook-login

I am currently working on a hybrid mobile app with Worklight and HTML5 stack. This app required a FB login functionality. I have implemented FB login mechanism into my app with FB Js SDK. Works fine if I view it inside mobile browser simulator, but when I deploy this app to the physical device, FB login buttons and functionality are not available (literally, they disappear from view).

Also, I want to display my FB login form in the same view instead of pop up window.

I wonder if using FB Js SDK is a good approach for hybrid app's? Or maybe should I use native code to build login mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same approach you used with facebook js sdk. It seems that "facebook js sdk" is for web apps and the site you are implementing have to be on a host. have you tried the cordova plugin for that? if you are using cordova,

try this one https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin 
and another great solution is [OpenFB](https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-open-fb)which bypasses the js sdk. 
and for your pop-up window problem try [InAPPBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md#orgapachecordovainappbrowser). But all of these are for cordova/Phonegap. But if you using another platform, I don't know any other solution rather than using JSONP to retrieve the fb login page over a remote host everytime you use the app.